# point /username to /[user]/[tab].js and not [user]/index.js in nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm attempting to create a user profile page that generates content based on the current *tab* the user is in.

The tab is decided based on what is passed in the URL (e.g. `/username/tab1`). The only issue with this is that one of the valid tabs the user can visit actually has a blank value (`/username`, to get the default tab).

However, when you enter this into the browser, **Next** automatically assumes I want to retrieve `/[user]/index.js` (which doesn't exist),  when in actuality what I want to get is `/[user]/[tab].js` and pass a blank value to the `tab` property in `context.query`.

Is this possible without creating a separate `index.js` and `[tab].js` file?

```
// Exported inside /pages/[user]/[tab].js
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const { page, tab } = context.query;

    // When we're on /username/foo it should output "foo".
    // When we're on /username it should output "".
    console.log(tab); 
};
```

Comment: Do you need a default value when destructuring? i.e.`const { page, tab = "" } = context.query`

Comment: @catgirlkelly No, I need `/page/` to still point to `/page/[tab].js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this using an [optional catch-all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes).

So, rename your `[tab].js` as `[[...tab]].js`, so it will catch also the requests to /username without a tab. Then in your code you'll handle tab as optional.

Comment: Wow. Incredible solution. Didn't even know something like this was possible. Thank you